# Get original type from DbEntityType

Tags: entity-framework

We have overriden the SaveChanges method because we want to set some final properties automatically upon saving and we have to set SETCONTEXT in each connection. Our current override looks as follows:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
  // Use basic SaveChanges if SessionInfo is not initialized
  if (SessionInfo.ContextInfo == null)
  {
    return base.SaveChanges();
  }

  // SessionInfo was initialized, so use custom logic now

  // Set the SqlId according to sessioninfo for each entity to add
  foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added))
  {
    string sqlIdPropertyName = 
      entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.First(x=>x.EndsWith("SqlId");
    entry.Property(sqlIdPropertyName).CurrentValue = SessionInfo.ServerSqlId;
  }
  // Set the IsDeleted boolean to true for each entity to delete
  foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted))
  {
    entry.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = true;
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
  }                 

  // Begin custom transaction if SessionInfo was set
  this.Database.Connection.Open();
  SessionInfo.SetContextInfo(this);
  int result = base.SaveChanges();
  this.Database.Connection.Close();
  return result;
}
```

As you can see, when we add a new record to the database, the save logic sets the SqlId for the object according to the SessionInfo. However, this now depends of PropertyNames.First(), which is a risk.

The PropertyName of the SqlId we want to set is always equal to the name of the POCO class type + SqlId, so for the class "Invoice" it would be "InvoiceSqlId".

How can we get the typename of the original POCO class from a DbEntityEntry?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `entry.Entity.GetType().Name`

EDIT - for when you may be using proxies

```
var entityType = entry.Entity.GetType();
string name;
if (entityType.BaseType != null && 
    entityType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
{
   name = entityType.BaseType.Name;
}
else
{
   name = entityType.Name
}
```

Comment: This unfortunally returns the type name of the Dynamic Proxy, and not the original class type.